# Index match excel multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Current test

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!$B$2:$B$20000,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!$U$2:$U$20000)*('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!N:N="Yes"))),"")
```

Explanation of what I want:

Bring through as the value from sheet fullList row B in external doc

with lookup value on sheet2@A2

To be checked against Row U in external spreadsheet but only if the corresponding value in row N = Yes

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes I think I picked up here:

- This is an array formula so `MATCH..,(range1=criteria1)*(range2=criteria2)` returns an array of 1s and 0s, so you can't look for your value in `Sheet2!A2` like you do.
- You also forgot that `MATCH` would need the third parameter to tell the function you want the first exact match.
- Your second range is a full column and should actually match the other range to not fail.

Taken these points into consideration I think you could try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!$B$2:$B$20000,MATCH(1,('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!$U$2:$U$20000=Sheet2!A2)*('[Soc Master List 19-20.xlsx]fullList'!$N$2:$N$20000="Yes"),0)),"")
```

Because this is an array formula you'll have to enter it through the key-combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>